# Replaces the textfile instead of pushing a data

Tags: c++

for some reason it replaces the textfile instead of pushing through it.. So we have this example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>


void puttingToText(
  std::string things[3],
  double thingsPoints[3]
  ){
    std::ofstream Thefile("players.txt");
    for(int i=0; i<=2; i++){
      Thefile << things[i] << " : " << thingsPoints[i] << std::endl;
    }

  }

void printingItems(


    std::string arrayHelpfull[3],
    double arrayHelpfullPoints[3],
    std::string arrayNone[3],
    double arrayNonePoints[3],
     std::string arrayHarmfull[3],
     double arrayHarmfullPoints[3],
    std::string option

    ) {
    std::cout << option << std::endl;

    if(option.compare("Plain") == 0){
      std::cout << arrayNone[0]
                  << " : "
                   << arrayNonePoints[0]
                   <<std::endl
                   << arrayNone[1]
                  << " : "
                   << arrayNonePoints[1]
                   <<std::endl
                   << arrayNone[2]
                  << " : "
                   << arrayNonePoints[2]
                   <<std::endl;

         puttingToText(arrayNone,arrayNonePoints);

    }
    else if(option.compare("Helpfull") == 0){

      std::cout << arrayHelpfull[0]
                  << " : "
                   << arrayHelpfullPoints[0]
                   <<std::endl
                   << arrayHelpfull[1]
                  << " : "
                   << arrayHelpfullPoints[1]
                   <<std::endl
                   << arrayHelpfull[2]
                  << " : "
                   << arrayHelpfullPoints[2]
                   <<std::endl;

      puttingToText(arrayHelpfull,arrayHelpfullPoints);
    }
    else{

          std::cout << arrayHarmfull[0]
                  << " : "
                   << arrayHarmfullPoints[0]
                   <<std::endl
                   << arrayHarmfull[1]
                  << " : "
                   << arrayHarmfullPoints[1]
                   <<std::endl
                   << arrayHarmfull[2]
                  << " : "
                   << arrayHarmfullPoints[2]
                   <<std::endl;
        puttingToText(arrayHarmfull,arrayHarmfullPoints);
    }

}


int main(){
  std::string arrayHelpfull[3] = {"fruits", "soda" , "candy"};
  double arrayHelpfullPoints[3] = {20.4,50.2,30.0};

    std::string arrayNone[3] = {"chair", "shoe" , "pencil"};
  double arrayNonePoints[3] = {0,0,0};

    std::string arrayHarmfull[3] = {"meth", "dirtyneedle","ninga"};
  double arrayHarmfullPoints[3] = {-20,-50,-30};

  int userChoice = 0;
    while (userChoice != 4) {

      std::cout << "1 - Just Plain Items"
            << std::endl
            << "2 - Helpfull Items"
            << std::endl
            << "3 - Harmfull Items"
            << std::endl
            << "4 - Quit"
            << std::endl;

        std::cin >> userChoice;

        switch (userChoice) {
        case 1:
            printingItems(
            arrayHelpfull, arrayHelpfullPoints, arrayNone,
              arrayNonePoints, arrayHarmfull, arrayHarmfullPoints, "Plain"
         );
            break;
        case 2:
        printingItems(
        arrayHelpfull, arrayHelpfullPoints, arrayNone,
              arrayNonePoints, arrayHarmfull, arrayHarmfullPoints, "Helpfull"
        );

            break;
        case 3:

        printingItems(
        arrayHelpfull, arrayHelpfullPoints, arrayNone,
              arrayNonePoints, arrayHarmfull, arrayHarmfullPoints, "Harmfull"
        );

            break;
        }


    }
}
```

You see... When i enter 1 for example the it dosent push the array, but replaces it.

One moment when i put the harmfull ones the textfile becomes this:

```
meth : -20
dirtyneedle : -50
ninga : -30
```

Next when i put plain items it becomes this:

```
chair : 0
shoe : 0
pencil : 0
```

I want to push it through like this:

```
meth : -20
dirtyneedle : -50
ninga : -30
chair : 0
shoe : 0
pencil : 0
```

Comment: Did you try to check if it opened it correctly?

Comment: Yes i did multiple times @FirstStep . you can see it on cloud9: https://ide.c9.io/uniforlyff/unifly

Comment: Try to add this line of code `TheFile.open("FileName.Ext",ios::app);` before your writting to file loop

Comment: Please check the path to "players.text", in case the file could not be opened, or you have no access rights, no text is written to the file.

Comment: Nvm i got solution... The reason was that i should have put this line :  std::ofstream Thefile("players.txt");   at the top.. so it dosent recreate every tme. Thanks @FirstStep For your time!

Comment: Sure no prob good luck with the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this line of code in order to *append* to a text file and not *replace* it:

```
TheFile.open("FileName.Ext",ios::app);
```

This should work:

```
  void puttingToText(
  std::string things[3],
  double thingsPoints[3]
  ){
    std::ofstream Thefile;
    Thefile.open("players.txt",ios::app);

    for(int i=0; i<=2; i++){
    Thefile << things[i] << " : " << thingsPoints[i] << std::endl;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Or you could put this:  std::ofstream Thefile("players.txt");   at the top of the file.. so it dosent replace.. Both Works! THanks for your time again!(3 min left)

Comment: Glad it helped. But one Q, what do you mean by to put it at the top of the file? you mean as a global variable? because it is already the first line of the function no?

Comment: By at top i mean make it a global variable.. And its not a global variable, the variable(already said variable three times...) was inside the function. So you need to make the variable at the very top. Here is the code i made: https://github.com/amanuel2/C-Examples/blob/master/Games/File-Handling/pt1/main.cpp

Comment: @ds Well if it works for you no one can stop you. But you should know that "globaling" a variable is not a good practice and here the file will be opened during the whole execution of your program and not just within the function. Anyway make sure to close it once you finish whatever the case: if within the function or at the end of your `main()`

Answer (score 1):

This line `std::ofstream Thefile("players.txt");` opens the file for creation, not appending. If the named file already exists, it is obliterated and overwritten.

See the [ofstream documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/) for more.